# Password validation in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I need password validation like

```
1 English uppercase characters (A – Z)
2 English lowercase characters (a – z)
3 Base 10 digits (0 – 9)
4 Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
5 Unicode characters
```

I have applied some code but result I am getting is an error.
I think regex I have used in wrong format. Please check my code and correct me.
Thanks

AuthController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|
                           regex:array("/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/")|
                           min:8|
                           confirmed',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Try [`regex:array('/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!$#%]*[!$#%]).*$/')`](https://regex101.com/r/xC2kT6/1). This regex requires all the 1-4 points and allows Point 5 (any characters).

Comment: @stribizhev I have tried this but getting an error "ErrorException in Validator.php line 1343: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Comment: Then just use another delimiter: `regex:array('~^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!$#%]*[!$#‌​%]).*$~'`

Comment: I have used regex:array("~^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!$#%]*[!$#‌‌​​%]).*$~") but error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex validator takes regex string, but you pass as an array.

Try to change your code

```
regex:array("/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/")
```

to

```
regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/
```

Also, look at @vks answer. His regex looks more clear.

P.S. When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

If the pipe `(|)` sigh is available in your regular expression pattern it could conflict with the separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).{3,}$
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I have added this in regex:array("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).{3,}$") but showing error "preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Comment: @samsam you missed the `delimiter` use `/` at both the ends

Comment: Code updated but still showing error regex:array("/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).{3,}$/")|

Comment: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @samsam use `~` instead of `/`